# getApplicationContext on a null object reference

Tags: kotlin, android-room

kotlin code

```
package com.example.room

import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import androidx.room.migration.Migration
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase

@Database(version = 3, entities = [User::class, Book::class])
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
    abstract fun bookDao(): BookDao
    companion object {

        private val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("create table Book (id integer primary key autoincrement not null, name text not null, pages integer not null)")
            }
        }

        private val MIGRATION_2_3 = object : Migration(2, 3) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("alter table Book add column author text not null default 'unknown'")
            }
        }

        private var instance: AppDatabase? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            instance?.let {
                return it
            }
            return Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "app_database")
                    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2, MIGRATION_2_3)
                    .build().apply {
                        instance = this
                    }
        }
    }

}
```

And the logcat is

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:122)
        at com.example.room.AppDatabase$Companion.getDatabase(AppDatabase.kt:39)
        at com.example.viewmodeltest.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:20)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1254)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3600)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3871) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2301) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8239) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at
```

Comment: Show your main activity code

Comment: From the stack trace I would guess that you pass the `MainActivity` (this) as context to `getDatabase` in the constructor of `MainActivity`. `MainActivity` doesn't exist until the constructor is completed so it's null.